# How can I remove temporary folders under Windows with R?

Tags: r, delete-file

After a session I would like to clean up my temporary folders, like for instance

```
d <- tempfile()
dir.create(d)
setwd(d)
# now work and sweave and latex etc
```

How can I remove `d` and its elements? `file.remove` fails.

Comment: It is not necessary. R itself will delete everything in temporary directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `unlink("d", recursive=TRUE)`. That should delete the folder and its contents.

Comment: Deleting the temporary directory with unlink is possible, but then subsequent use of the tempdir in this session, such as trying to write a temporary file `write.csv("aaa",file.path(tempdir(),"file.txt"))` will return the error `cannot open file '/tmp/RtmpXRQJYF/file.txt': No such file or directory`. One has to restart R to use tempdir() again.

Answer (score 4):

Try `?unlink`. Depends on what os you are using but this:

```
unlink(d, recursive=TRUE)
```

Should work. If you want to delete the contents and reuse the folder you could try this:

```
file.remove(dir(d, full.names=TRUE))
```